# LinkPager not showing anything

Tags: php, pagination, yii2

I've been stuck for hours trying to see where I went wrong. Just started yii2 a few days ago, so I'm thinking maybe I'm missing something really simple, please help.
I'm trying to implement a `LinkPager` widget.
Steps on how i did it:

1. Created a pagination object ($pagination) in controller (yii\data\Pagination). It has a totalCount from my Query statement and pageSize.

   ```
       $query = myModel::aFunctionThatReturnsaQueryType();
       $countQuery = clone $query;
       $pagination = new Pagination([
       'totalCount' => $countQuery->count(),
       'pageSize' => '9',
   ]);
   ```
2. This is in my view

   ```
   echo LinkPager::widget([
       'pagination' => $pagination,
   ]);
   ```

But my problem is that nothing is showing up after the echo. What did I miss?

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: no i'm not. There's no error. It just doesnt echo anything.

Comment: Hello, i dont know what i did but now its suddenly working, i will trace my steps and post what i found out later. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Linker settings isnt visible if there are less items or exact number of items as the size per page. it only shows itself when data is more than ur sizeperpage. (T.T I noticed too late)

Answer (score 0):

I find on core yii2 and found that you need set `pageSizeParam` to not be the default: just look like at DataProvider:

```
'pagination' => ['pageSize' => 20,'pageSizeParam'=>false,],
```

Everything will done. Have nice a day :)